# Visual Studio Changes the Code After Saving

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017

Apologies if this already has an answer but I'm not quite sure what keywords would take me to the solution.

I have an ASP project with a quite big ASPX file. Every time after I make changes to this file and save via CTRL+S or using the disk icon, VS changes a big bulk of the HTML code down the bottom of the file. It seems to be adding some `<br/>` tags, changing the indentation, and doing some other minor edits. However sometimes this cause bugs along the line. I want this feature to be turned off but can't find how.

Thanks SO.

Comment: Do you have some sort of extension installed and running doing this? Maybe try turning an extension off if its troublesome?

Comment: @drzounds no. I think I might have an answer although I'm not sure. I will share it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I've realised there were some incorrect closing tags (i.e `</br>` instead of `<br/>`). I'm quite confident that this triggers VS to run some automation after saving. Also there are further incorrect HTML in the code for example `<ul>` tags are wrapped by `<p>` tags.

I've unchecked `Auto insert close tag` under **Tools > Text Editor > HTML (Web Forms) > Formatting**. This didn't help first but later on fixed itself when I've restarted VS. This issue has been on and off so this might not be a correct answer but I'm sharing anyways.